# I'm trying to build a web app using flask, but changes I make to the CSS no longer reflect on it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

The changes used to reflect on it when I'd refresh the page, but then it just stopped and stayed stuck on that same style. Changes I make to the html and the python code continue to reflect on it though. I read a similar question here about it, that made me notice that the terminal now says

```
Restarting with stat
```

instead of

```
Restarting with reloader
```

I tried installing the `watchdog` package like that thread had suggested, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: Yes, browser cache.  Additionally, if you ‘view source’ from the browser, and click on your css link, it’ll open the css file in the browser window and you’ll be able to see what the browser is using.  After clearing the cache and refreshing, you’ll see a change in the css file.

Answer (score 1):

You "cache bust" the CSS by appending the modification stamp of the file. Something like

```
css_path = os.path.join(os.dirname(__file__), 'static', 'style.css')
css_time = int(os.stat(css_path).st_mtime)
...
@app.context_processor
def inject_css_mtime()
    return {'css_mtime', css_mtime}
```

This makes `css_mtime` available to templates.

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}?v={{ css_mtime }}">
```

When the .css file changes, its mtime will change, and browsers will know to request it again. Adjust the `css_path` calculation to match your app structure.

You'll need to do this for any JavaScript files, too.